# C 2d array Class

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, heap-memory

I have to create a new `img_t` with initial size rows and cols. If successful(memory allocation succeeds), returns a pointer to a newly allocated `img_t`.

I am not able to initialize rows and cols.

```
typedef struct { 
    uint8_t** pixels;
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
} img_t;

/// A type for returning status codes 

typedef enum {
    IMG_OK,
    IMG_BADINPUT,
    IMG_BADARRAY,
    IMG_BADCOL,
    IMG_BADROW,
    IMG_NOTFOUND
} img_result_t;

//something is wrong in this constructor*******
img_t* img_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols){
        img_t **arr = malloc(rows * sizeof(img_t*));
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
           arr[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(img_t));
           arr[i]->rows = rows;
      
           return arr[i]; 
        }
        return 0; 
    }

// helper function that prints the content of the img
void print_img(img_t* im) {
    if (im == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid img (null).\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Printing img of row length %d and col length %d:\n", im->rows, im->cols);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<im->rows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<im->cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", im->pixels[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main() {
    // test variables to hold values returned by the functions
    img_t* test_im = NULL;
    img_result_t test_result = IMG_OK;

    // test task 01 & 02
    printf("Creating test_im by calling 'img_create(10, 10)'\n");
    test_im = img_create(10, 10);
    if (test_im == NULL) {
        printf("test_im == NULL\n");
        return 1; //exit with a non-zero value
    }
    printf("test_im\n");
    printf("Printing test_im\n");
    print_img(test_im);
}
```

Program output:

```
test_im
Printing test_im
Printing img of row length 10 and col length 0:
```

Comment: `return arr[i];` You do understand that `return` immediately terminates the function? That means that the `for` loop only ever runs once. Also, it is clear you are meant to make a 2D array for the pixels` field and not the whole `img_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your types and sizes are all over the place. You are constructing an array of `img_t *` sized objects, of length rows, and then returning immediately in the first iteration of your loop (after allocating too much memory for your structure).

You're not setting `cols` or `pixels`, and are leaking the memory held by `arr`.

`img_create` should return a pointer to an `img_t` structure. This structure contains the 2D array of `uint8_t`, and the dimensions.

```
img_t *img_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols) {
    img_t *img = malloc(sizeof *img);

    img->rows = rows;
    img->cols = cols;
    img->pixels = malloc(rows * sizeof *img->pixels);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        img->pixels[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof *img->pixels[i]);

    return img;
}
```

This example uses [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc), to initialize each row to contain zeroes. The `*alloc` functions may return `NULL` - you'll need to consider what to do in that event.

To [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) this structure, reverse the steps.

Also note, the proper [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) specifier for `unsigned int` is `"%u"`, and for `uint8_t` it is defined in the macro [`PRIu8`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

A working example:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t **pixels;
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
} img_t;

img_t *img_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols) {
    img_t *img = malloc(sizeof *img);

    img->rows = rows;
    img->cols = cols;
    img->pixels = malloc(rows * sizeof *img->pixels);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        img->pixels[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof *img->pixels[i]);

    return img;
}

void print_img(img_t *img) {
    if (img == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid img (null).\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Printing img of row length %u and col length %u:\n",
            img->rows, img->cols);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < img->rows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < img->cols; j++)
            printf("%" PRIu8 " ", img->pixels[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void img_destroy(img_t *img) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < img->rows; i++)
        free(img->pixels[i]);
    free(img->pixels);
    free(img);
}

int main(void) {
    img_t *i = img_create(10, 10);

    print_img(i);

    img_destroy(i);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for making it so clear. another thing, what do i do incase i dont want to initialize my row to contain zeros, just want allocate the memory?

Comment: @robin110 Simply use `malloc` instead, but know that accessing uninitialized data is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). You must initialize this data at some point before its use. I used `calloc` so that your `print_img` function could be tested right away, and you could see some results (rows and rows of `0`).

Comment: @robin110 I've updated the answer with a more complete example. Please do consider [accepting the answer if it best solves your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)